# Large sized SQL Server database vs deadlocks?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, deadlock

I am looking at a SQLServer database having sized **751 GB** and is accessed in 100 countries with multiple users in the world.

Since last few months this database is experiencing deadlocks on few tables.

I am suspecting this huge size could have impact on database locks. I looked at indexes and stored procedures and applied `update lock` on tables when using in select query.

Still no impact.

Comment: question lacks any useful context

Comment: a small, poorly configured/written database can experience deadlocks....

Comment: A single user database will never have a deadlock, no matter how large.  Size has little to do with it.

Comment: I am looking at a sql server database having sized 751GB and accessed in 100 countries with multiple users in the world. Since last few months this database is experiencing deadlocks on few tables.

Answer (score 0):

If there are users that will only be using the table for reporting purposes(and the data they are querying isn't changing too rapidly), they could always use the SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED function.

This will not lock the table when running a select statement.  However, you really do need to use this wisely...as many SQL experts will tell you that your results could potentially be incorrect.  However, it will potentially help lower the amount of deadlocks you are seeing.

Check this page out for more info https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29#READ_UNCOMMITTED_.28dirty_reads.29

Answer (score 0):

You need to analyze where the deadlocks are happening. It has nothing to do with the size of your database (or in how many countries it is being used) as such.. It is just a question of accessing the data and the patterns how the application that uses the database behaves.

Typically a deadlock happens when one process is reading records and another one is updating them, and both of them need to get more locks to the data, but are not able to because the other one already has a lock on those rows and neither of them can continue until the other one has finished -- and at that point SQL Server notices the problem and the deadlock happens.

The deadlock can happen to either the data or the index, and you should check which one it is, it might help you figuring out what's going on.

For fixing the issue, if you can change the pattern so that the data is always accessed in the same order, then deadlocks should not appear.

Another way is to look into the statements and see how much I/O is involved. If the statements involve for example a scan, creating a new index might fix the issue. Then the process needs to access significantly less pages and chances for deadlock will decrease.

If it's busy database with lot of different actions happening on the same tables all the time, it might not be possible to get rid of all the deadlocks, so you should also come up with a target, how many deadlocks is ok.

I personally would stay away from dirty reads (isolation level read uncommitted / with NOLOCK) with the exception of some very special cases where using it might be helpful, because it can cause serious side-affects too, like reading the same data more than once. This of course depends a lot on the type of data / application you're dealing with.